# Angular how to handle multiple HTTP calls

Tags: angular, http

I have two HTTP sequence call as below :

1. Reading data from JSON file : which gives me a "URL" from JSON file
2. GET/POST API Call : using URL from 1.

I used below code :

```js
 this.httpClient.get('/api/apiserver.json').subscribe(
      apipath => {
        if (apipath['server'] !== undefined) {
          
          this.httpClient.get(apipath['server'] + '/api/manual/xyz?parameter1=' + parameterid).subscribe(
          (data: any[]) => {
            // Binding and showing user data
         }
        )
       }
     });
```

I don't want to call API 1 every time i.e. Can I write HTTP logic somewhere and use it globally across project and then sequentially in component for other GET/POST API call.
Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, you can. Write it in a service.

Comment: Go through Angular docs on how to use [Service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: @eku take a look into different rxjs operators it'll help you when you're dealing with multiple http requests.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You can create a new service and call the API1 in there in a method like this -

```
getMethod() {
  return this.httpClient.get('/api/apiserver.json')
}
```

Then, you can subscribe to this method whenever/wherever you need to. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but API 2 is dependent on API 1 data. So getMethod() would be called first and won't get caught in async issue.  I am bit new to angular, please advice.